# powerview in sharepoint 2013 app

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, powerview

We got a requirement to embed powerview graphs and powerpivot tables in sharepoint 2013 app.  I am new to sharepoint app development. 
Please direct me with some reference articles.

Thanks
MM

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure you have Enterprise Version of SharePoint. Then you need to configure SharePoint BI features. Activate BI features requires set of configurations on SQL/SharePoint, Possibly Kerberos configuration etc. You will get an overview of how to install/configure BI features at:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231671.aspx. You will also get an step by step instructions at  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/querysimon/archive/2012/11/26/installing-the-bi-features-of-sharepoint-2013.aspx.